# Two different Modules for two different domain in a Single Angular 6 project hosted on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, angular6, serverless

The current scenario is that I have a Serverless application built on Angular 6 and Lambdas(Node Js) and its front end hosted on S3 as a static website. Now the requirement is that we need to point two different modules of the application with two different domains, the 1st portal with  www.domain1.com and 2nd portal with www.domain2.com.

Is it possible? If yes, please provide the suggestion. Any help is highly appreciable.

Comment: Just curious, why are they not two different applications?

Comment: Yes I know they should be two different applications, but I need to configure an existing project in this way. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic conditional routing:

```js
const environment = {
  production: true,
  APIEndpoint: (value) => value ? 'www.domain1.com' : 'www.domain2.com'
}

const URL = `${environment.APIEndpoint(true)}/api/methods`;

console.log(URL); // www.domain1.com/api/methods
```